# Datepicker is not working when i go to the previous page in the form?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 4 forms.In that, 2nd form will have one datepicker field.If I moved to 3rd form and when I came back to 2nd form the date picker is not working.

The datepicker code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#dob").datepicker({ maxDate: "-18Y"});
  jQuery('.fa-calendar').click(function() {
    jQuery("#dob").focus();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that form events are not clearing the events and also check that form 3 does not have element with same ID

Comment: Thank u so much.. Issue is form events are clearing everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite vague as we don't know what datepicker you're using, but I'd certainly recommend against using the `.click` function in jQuery, try this with an `on` bind and see if you still get the same issue:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#dob").datepicker({ maxDate: "-18Y"});
  jQuery('.fa-calendar').on('click', function() {
    jQuery("#dob").focus();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the best thing you could do right now @Mathi would be to create a codepen or JSfiddle to explain your code a bit more.